# How do I manually select an option in a Angular2 select list?

Tags: angular, select, dropdown, reset

I feel like this should be super easy but I just can't get it to work. I'm taking over a project from someone else so there's large chunks already finished.
I have non-dynamic select list defined in my HTML.

```
<form class="form-group">
   <select class="form-control" (change)="changePreset();>
     <option value="">Please choose a preset</option>
     <option value="preset1" >Preset 1</option>
     <option value="preset2" >Preset 2</option>
     <option value="preset3" >Preset 3</option>
     <option value="preset4" >Preset 4</option>
     <option value="preset5" >Preset 5</option>
   </select>
</form>
```

Everything works fine so far. 
There's a Reset button on the page that resets all data in the app when clicked, and therefore also needs to reset this dropdown. The data in the app resets already, all I need to do is reassign this dropdown to its first "Please choose a preset" option.

How do I do this? Is there some quick simple way to target the select list and assign a selectedIndex or something?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it just the data that gets reset or does the html refresh to?

Comment: Do you mean the page or the select component?  The rest of the html page resets with its data fine, it's just this dropdown. I just need it to visually go back to showing the initial "Please choose..." option. Choosing this doesn't do anything behind the scenes since it's value is empty. Right now when the rest of the page resets the dropdown stays on its previously selected option and doesn't show the "Please choose..." Option.

Answer (score 1):

HI @Hopper use the ngModel for binding in Angular

You Template Would be like that

```
Selected Value :- {{presetModel}}

<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="presetModel" (change)="changePreset()">
  <option value="">Please choose a preset</option>
  <option value="preset1">Preset 1</option>
  <option value="preset2">Preset 2</option>
  <option value="preset3">Preset 3</option>
  <option value="preset4">Preset 4</option>
  <option value="preset5">Preset 5</option>
</select>

<button (click)="reset()">Reset</button>
```

And Your component class will be

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core'; 


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './src/app/app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent{ 
    presetModel:string =""; 


   changePreset(){
       // TODO this.presetModel
   }

   reset(){
       this.presetModel = "";
   }

}
```

[Link for Plunker for this](https://plnkr.co/edit/vu4hsYUoLyFiEpUBhlF8?p=preview)

Comment: OMG Thank you, this worked for me! I knew it was something super simple that I just wasn't seeing!